# Can I authenticate with Google username and password in Google Drive API?

Tags: google-drive-api

Can I authenticate with just Google account username and password instead of using OAuth? If not, is it planned to support this kind of authentication in the future versions of Google Drive API?

I am currently using [Google Documents List API](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/documents-list/) which allows to authenticate with just username and password. So I am wondering if I can I do the same thing with Google Drive API.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Are there any reasons you cannot use OAuth 2.0 as your authorization mechanism?

Client Login is currently being [deprecated](http://googledevelopers.blogspot.com/2012/04/changes-to-deprecation-policies-and-api.html) and it would be better for you and your users to use OAuth 2.0.

There are multiple code samples available in the [Drive SDK documentation](https://developers.google.com/drive/credentials) as well as in the various client libraries project page to help you get started.

Comment: Yes, I can not use OAuth because my application is command line, and it is supposed to be run on Linux server that does not have a graphical interface.

Comment: You don't really need a graphical interface on the device itself. You can set up authorization on another computer (e.g through SSH) using the [Native Application flow](https://developers.google.com/accounts/docs/OAuth2InstalledApp): the app will generate a URL that you will have to visit while authenticated and copy a code back to the app.

Comment: Thank you for the details, Alain. Using another computer with GUI  to authenticate the server app is not an option for me, as it complicates the workflow. It looks like I have no choice but continue using 'Documents List API' for now.

Answer (score 0):

If you are running a server application, consider using a service account with OAuth2 and the Drive API. This will allow you to run the app on a server without a user having to provide OAuth2 credentials on the console or through a UI. You can also do impersonation if you want your app to act on documents with a specific account.

```
 GoogleCredentials credentials = new GoogleCredential.Builder()
            .setTransport(HTTP_TRANSPORT)
            .setJsonFactory(JSON_FACTORY)
            .setServiceAccountId("[[SERVICE_ACCOUNT_EMAIL]]")
            .setServiceAccountScopes(DriveScopes.DRIVE, DriveScopes.DRIVE_FILE,
                "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.email",
                "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.profile")
            .setServiceAccountPrivateKeyFromP12File(Auth.keyFile)
            .setServiceAccountUser("[[impersonateduser@domain]]")
            .build();
    credentials.refreshToken();
```

Answer (score 0):

I've found this blog post somewhere (possibly here): http://blog.databigbang.com/automated-browserless-oauth-authentication-for-twitter/.

I know it is regarding Twitter, but it uses the same method, so I reckon it just needs a little tweak in the names. In short: if the script is run only by server, install Jython + HTMLUnit, simulate user going to the generated authorization link and clicking 'allow access' button and get token.